# Convert API Response from JSON into R Data DataFrame

Tags: r, api, flask, shiny

I've built a Flask API which is returning JSON response and I'm looking for an elegant way I can read this HTML JSON into a R dataframe?  Here is the code from the API:

```
 @app.route('/get_model_results/<upload_id>', methods=['GET'])
 def get_model_results(upload_id):
     upload_id = str(upload_id)
     path_for_model_results = '/app/flask_app/model_results_' + upload_id + '.csv'
     return pd.read_csv(path_for_model_results).to_json(orient='records')
```

In my R shiny code, I'm using httr and retrieving the JSON, but it comes back as HTML.  Here is my shiny code:

```
library(httr)
get_model_results <- function(upload_id) {
upload_url <- paste0(BACKEND_URL, "/get_model_results/", upload_id)
request <- httr::GET(upload_url, encoding = 'UTF-8')
out <- httr::content(request)
out
```

}

Here is a snippet of the response:

```
model_df<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><p>[{"central_time":"2020-04-07 15:47:00","Va_V":283.312}]</p></body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your responses are all in this format, the easiest thing to do is strip out the json and parse it:

```r
jsonlite::fromJSON(strsplit(strsplit(out, "<p>")[[1]][2], "</p>")[[1]][1])

#>          central_time    Va_V
#> 1 2020-04-07 15:47:00 283.312
```

Comment: I ran that command:  Warning: Error in strsplit: non-character argument

Comment: @jKraut that means you haven't got `out` as text. Try `out <- httr::content(request, "text")`